# Mathematic equation of Crankshaft Efficiency

Tags: calculus, integration, vectors, physics

I need to find an Mathematic equation of Crankshaft Efficiency. The question is related to engine performance. The research I have done indicated that crankshaft has a poor conversion rate to create torque force. Please refer to the math equation I have developed.
[image]

Even if the piston force is a constant force, the torque force will not be a constant output. I need to develop the mathematic equation on how much energy is used by the crankshaft.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to show your attempt.

Comment: When you say "how much energy is used by the crankshaft" do you mean over a specific period of time or just its efficiency over, say, a single revolution

Comment: @HenryLee Only need to find out half of a revolution. Specifically when the angle is in the range of 0<a<180. For a real engine though the force on piston is not constant. The calculation would be quite complicated.